# Why my data is not inserting into databse

Tags: php, jquery

I created a subscribe button using PHP. Whenever I hit subscribe button, instead of going to the database it gets stuck on the filter_var() PHP code that echo's Put correct email. After a lot of thinking I am unable to figure out the problem.
Here is my PHP code

```
<?php 
include 'conn.php';
   $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      $sql= "SELECT * FROM subscribe WHERE email='$email'";
      $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      $row=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($email=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       echo "<span style='color:red'>*you are already subscribed</span>";
    }else{
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      echo "<span>Put correct email<span>";
    }else{
       $enter= "INSERT INTO `subscribe` (`id`, `email`) VALUES (NULL, '$email');";

       msqli_query($conn, $enter);
       echo "<span style='color:green;'>Thank you for subscribing";
    }
  }
  } else{
    echo "something went wrong";
  }
?>
```

See this code

```
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      echo "<span>Put correct email<span>";
```

It gets stuck in this part while the upper part is working fine, i.e when I put the same email It runs the echo function.

I am also using jquery to run the function on the same page

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#subscribe-form').submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var email=$("input[name='email']").val();
            var submit=$("#submit").val();
            $('.sub').load('subscription.inc.php', {
                email:email,
                submit:submit
            })
        });
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: It's obvious that email address is not in correct format. Also you should filter email before executing any query.

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` returns an array of matching fields, so the test will always be true.

Comment: But I am using else statements to execute the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove Id from your query if you have auto increment. because database manage itself.
And you have typo here.

```
msqli_query($conn, $enter);
```

it should be

```
mysqli_query($conn, $enter);
```

And change

```
if ($email=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

With

```
if ($row>0) {
```

Full code:`subscription.inc.php`

```
 <?php 
include 'conn.php';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
  $sql= "SELECT * FROM subscribe WHERE email='$email'";
  $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $row=mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if ($row>0) {
    echo "<span style='color:red'>*you are already subscribed</span>";
  }
  else
  {
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      echo "<span>Put correct email<span>";
    }
    else
    {
      $enter= "INSERT INTO `subscribe` (`email`) VALUES ('$email')";
      mysqli_query($conn, $enter);
      echo "<span style='color:green;'>Thank you for subscribing";
    }
  }
}

?>
```

And html form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post" action="subscription.inc.php" id="subscribe-form"> 
    <input type='text' placeholder="enter your email" name="email" id="#email">
    <br/> 
    <button class="btn" role="button" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"> subscribe </button> 
    <p class="sub"></p> 
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: bro I can't chat with you

Comment: there is no option

Comment: Don’t worry i will help you give me your fb messanger i will ping you

Comment: Ayush Bhambore search it. Profile picture of Zayn malik

Answer (score 1):

Please change condition:

```
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  echo "<span>Put correct email<span>";
```

to:

```
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  echo "<span>Put correct email<span>";
```

because `filter_var()` returns filtered text. and in this it return some text so condition gets true.